# Jbpm6.1.0 console not working - Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit.“jbpm-console.war”.WeldService:

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jbpm, wildfly-8

I'm getting below error while starting the jboss the server.
Just i installed the JBPM 6.1.0 and trying to start the server and deployment also getting fail.

Please advise...

> 2014-09-16 12:16:54,008 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014613: Operation
>   ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure
>   description: {
>       "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector
>   is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".beanmanager]"],
>       "JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
>           "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".INSTALL"],
>           "Services that may be the cause:" => [
>               "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".beanmanager",
>               "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
>               "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
>           ]
>       } }
>
> 2014-09-16 12:16:54,046 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server]
>   (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018565: Replaced deployment
>   "jbpm-console.war" with deployment "jbpm-console.war" 2014-09-16
>   12:16:54,048 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller]
>   (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
>   JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
>         service jboss.naming.context.java.app.jbpm-console (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".INSTALL]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.naming.context.java.module.jbpm-console.jbpm-console
> ```
>
> (unavailable) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".INSTALL]  JBAS014777:
>   Services which failed to start:      service
>   jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: JBAS015811: Failed
>   to start the http-interface service
>         service jboss.jacorb.poa-service.rootpoa: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.jacorb.poa-service.rootpoa: JBAS016490: Failed to resolve
>   initial reference RootPOA
>         service jboss.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.undertow.listener.default: Could not start http listener

Answer (score 2):

This means that there is another server in the same port that jboss is using: 
"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.listener.default: Could not start http listener", if that's not the issue, please provide the full stack trace.
Regards